Is it possible to play the audio file after receiving user's permissions once to play audio?
I am trying to play audio without any user interaction and getting error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

Here is my code:
<audio id="beep">
    <source src="~/Content/Sounds/beep.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script>
var playAudio = $("#beep")[0];
playAudio.play();
</script>

As I understand its denied by current browsers to play audio without explicit user interaction. Is it possible somehow when  the page is loaded ask user for permission to play audio and only after user's explicit permission load the page, then call this code in JS whenever I need it?

There doesn't seem to be a listed browser/DOM permission entry for playing audio - so you'll need to simply ask the user to manually click the Play button in your <audio> element.

I need it without further interaction because this sound will be some kind of notification about some event happened in backend, so user is informed about it.

You could probably trigger the permission request on first interaction and hopefully the sound will play once the backend event happens. Remember the user can still choose not to give permission.

User interaction basically means when the user clicks anywhere on the page. The following example features a <dialog> prompting the user to either permit the audio to play or deny it. Details are commented in the example. Responsively it's decent but it looks great if viewed in Full page mode.


// Reference <dialog>
const modal = document.querySelector("dialog");
// Reference <form>
const io = document.forms[0];
// Load the audio object
const mp3 = new Audio("https://glsbx.s3.amazonaws.com/-/dd.mp3");
// If it's an <audio> reference like normal.
// const mp3 = document.querySelector("audio");

// Open <dialog>
modal.showModal();
// Pre-adjust audio volume
mp3.volume = 0.5;

/**
 * This event handler determines if the audio will be played 
 * depending on which <button> the user clicked.
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 */
const player = event => {
  // Determine which element the user clicked
  const clk = event.target;
  // If the user clicked button#no...
  if (clk.id === "no") {
    // close the <dialog> and...
    modal.close();
    // end the function
    return;
  }
  // If the user clicked button#yes...
  if (clk.id === "yes") {
    // close the <dialog>...
    modal.close();
    // play the audio and...
    mp3.play();
    // end the function
    return;
  }
};

/*
  Register the <form> to listen for any "click" events fired on 
  itself or any of it's children. When the "click" event is 
  triggered function player() will be called.
*/
io.addEventListener("click", player);
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI";
}

dialog {
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem 1.25rem;
  border: 1.51515px outset rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: rgb(38, 57, 77) 0px 20px 30px -10px;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(38, 57, 77, 0.4)
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 14px 28px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 10px 10px;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: -0.25rem;
}

sup {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.2em;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: smaller;
}

button {
  float: right;
  width: 4rem;
  padding: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details {
  font-size: smaller;
  interpolate-size: allow-keywords;
}

details::details-content {
  transition: block-size 1s, content-visibility 1s allow-discrete;
  overflow: hidden;
  block-size: 0;
}

details[open]::details-content {
  block-size: auto;
}

summary {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

summary::before {
  content: '✤';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1ch;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

details[open] summary::before {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#yes {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
}
<dialog>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Autoplay Policy</legend>
      <p>In compliance with autoplay policy of your browser<sup>✤</sup> this site will only play audio with your explicit permission. Please choose your preference.</p>
      <button id="yes" type="button">Permit</button>
      <button id="no" type="button">Deny</button>
      <footer>
        <details>
          <summary>More on autoplay policies</summary>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay" target="_blank">Chrome</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide" target="_blank">Firefox</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/" target="_blank">iOS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </footer>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</dialog>



